# Is it possible to use multi-threading effectively for a short period of time

Tags: multithreading, winapi, synchronization

Consider I have a one-thread code that does something in the main thread and it takes about 10-20 ms. I would like to utilize two cores of my processor and split the task for two threads living at different cores. Technically I should probably resume two sleeping threads and make myself to sleep until they're done and sleep again. Nothing scaring if the task is long enough to execute. But for 10-20 ms I suspect the penalty of using well-known synchronization techniques would cost me a large share of time. If I'm too suspicious and the Windows/CPU does good job making all sleeping/waking requests effective, then what is the smallest time it still makes sense to split, 1ms, 10ms, 100ms?

Comment: With a well written code synchronization expenses might be just a few milliseconds. That is with two cores and well splittable task your 10 ms would be, let's say, 2 ms sync expense + 10/2 ms computational cost. A small gain, but it's already here. The larger the task is, the more is the benefit then.

Comment: Have you used a performance profiler to identify the bottlenecks in your application? Unless this is a specific bottleneck, I wouldn't bother, although it will improve performance.

Comment: Why not try it?  Typical synchro latency is measured in ns, not ms.

Comment: @Samuel_Neff. Actually I thought about such optimization looking at the performance of graphics scaling primitive that took 10 ms at many years Celeron 1.7Ghz and modern iCore. But the latter has 2 cores and the logic can be easily splitted vertically, so one thread working on (0..Height/2) of destination bitmap and another - (Height/2 + 1.. Height). So if the penalty is low, I should see gain in the speed of this function

Answer (score 4):

Multi-threading using an existing threadpool (existing sleeping threads) can speed up a 10-20ms operation.

The specific synchronization calls to wake up the threads and join them are miniscule, far less than 1ms.

One thing to be aware of is locality of reference. If the code running on multiple threads is accessing the same memory, then the CPUs will have to synchronize memory access which could reduce the actual performance improvement.

Equally if the threads are using common resources and require locking or other thread synchronization, waiting on these locks would degrade performance.

If there is any I/O in these threads, then splitting it into threads will help speed it up the most.

Comment: I suppose that my code will definitely access different parts of memory for writing, but might access the same segments for reading. Does the performance drop depend on the architecture and CPU generation in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Unless this short task is called a lot of times (i.e. in a loop) there is no point because at best you are going to save yourself 10ms processing time even before you account for any task switching/thread starting/syncing...

Comment: Yes, there should be multiply calls as a result of multiply responses to events.

Comment: Is your response time per event less than 40-50ms? If not, you should be able to find some other task that will use higher proportion of total time.

Comment: Actually it's a mix of multiply events and loops you mentioned. The time between sure less than 40-50ms

Answer (score 1):

If your have many tasks and your working threads continuously take tasks from common queue (like in ExecutorService), overhead for a task is 1..10 microseconds. Fork/Join facility is even more effective. Thread switching is most expensive action, so instead of resuming 2 sleeping threads and making master thread to wait, better run one task on master thread and only one on the worker thread.

Comment: That's the problem. I would do all the threads continuously running, but this is wrong. You said that switching a thread between sleep and awakening is expensive? Can you point to a source? Is it the same for every architecture/generation of CPUs?

Comment: _"Fork/Join facility is even more effective"_ maybe I don't understand what you're saying, but forking and joining are pretty much the slowest operations possible. Ideally you want to keep threads running almost all of the time without ever blocking, and blocking on an event object when the work queue is empty.

Comment: Maksee, look at http://codeidol.com/java/java-concurrency/Performance-and-Scalability/Costs-Introduced-by-Threads/

Comment: Damon, Fork/Join does not necessarily do actual fork and join under the hood, it replaces switching with recursion when possible.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: +1 My bad, seems you talked about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_queue). That's basically what you do when you manually schedule to several fast forward queues, too. Agreed, this can be very fast, though if sub-tasks do not take exactly the same time, it runs sub-optimally.

Comment: @Damon: not exacltly, I meant http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: Hmm... that is basically an army of ForkJoinTasks, i.e. Future objects from dividing tasks recursively up to some threshold. So, whatever Java uses as the underlying mechanism for Future (probably a thread pool and a stock task queue, but I wouldn't know), with a lot of overhead added for recursion, object creation, and garbage collection, and no in-order processing. The docs claim to provide work stealing, but honestly I don't see how it is to magically achieve this simply by dividing recursively and creating lots of futures.

Comment: @Damon, I did not look inside, but I've programmed a couple of tasks using both fork/join and threadpool from java.util concurrent. Fork/join is faster.

Comment: It's interesting in any case, if for no other reason than for curiosity... I'll try to find out what exactly is below it, and if I don't figure it out, I'll open a question on that tomorrow :-)